# create validation rule in cakephp ,which can use as core validation rules

Tags: cakephp

can we create  validation rules, which can work as a core validation rule.

Suppose I want to use a validation function which can be use for  input fields.Means I have a function like:

```
function checkinput($input)
   {
     $arr=array('x','y','z');
     if(in_array($input,$arr))
        return false;
     else
        return true;
   }
```

Now I want to use this function as the validation in all models. suppose for this function a custom rule has been created, name checkinput.
I want to use this validation in any model as:

```
var $validate = array(
   'name' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Please provide a name.',
        ),
        'checkinput' => array(
            'rule' => 'checkinput',
            'message' => "You can't use X,Y,Z as name.",
        ),
    ));
```

Can this kind of custom validation rule be created in behaviour or by other method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you: "Custom validation rules"
http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/07/19/extended-core-validation-rules/

and
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/10/07/maximum-power-for-your-validation-rules/
with code in github

Note that you need to array_shift first (see debug output for details):

```
function validateCustom($field) {
    $field = array_shift($field);
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to place the function in your `app_model.php` (or `AppModel.php` depending on which version of Cake you are using. This will give all your models access to the function for validation/other purposes.

To quote the manual:

> Model/behavior methods are checked first, before looking for a method
>   on the Validation class. This means that you can override existing
>   validation methods (such as alphaNumeric()) at an application level
>   (**by adding the method to AppModel**), or at model level.

Answer (score 0):

We have posted the validation rules. this example best for validation in cakephp.

```
public $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
            'rule' => array('custom', '/^[a-z0-9]{1,}$/i'),
            'message' => 'Alphabets and numbers only'
        ),
    'user_name' => array(
        'isUnique' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'The username has already been taken.',
        ),
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' =>  array('custom','/^[a-z0-9]{1,}$/i'),
            'message' => 'Alphabets and numbers only',
        ),
    ),

    /*'password' => array(
        'rule' => array('minLength', 6),
        'message' => 'Passwords must be at least 6 characters long.',
    ),*/
    'password1' => array(
    'password' => array(
        'rule'    => '/^[a-z0-9]{1,}$/i',
        'message' => 'Only letters and integers'
        ),

        'between' => array(
            'rule'    => array('between', 6, 50),
            'message' => 'Between 6 to 50 characters'
        ),),
    'confirm_password' => array(
        'equaltofield' => array(
        'rule' => array('equaltofield','password1'),
        'message' => 'Password does not match.',
        //'allowEmpty' => false,
        //'required' => false,
        //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
        'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
        'compare'    => array(
            'rule'      => array('validate_passwords'),
            'message' => 'The passwords you entered do not match.',
        )

    ),
    'email_address' => array(
        'email' => array(
            'rule' => array('custom','/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+([A-Za-z0-9]{2,4}|museum)$/i'),
            'message' => 'Please provide a valid email address.',
        ),
        'isUnique' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'Email address already in use.',
        ),
        )

    );

    function equaltofield($check,$otherfield)
    {
        //get name of field
        $fname = '';

        foreach ($check as $key => $value){
            $fname = $key;
            break;
        }



        return $this->data[$this->name][$otherfield] === $this->data[$this->name][$fname];
    } 
    /*public  function beforeValidate(){

        return true;
    }*/
    public function validate_passwords() {
            return $this->data[$this->alias]['password1'] === $this->data[$this->alias]['confirm_password'];
    }
```